# Django context variable as inline css property's value

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

i'm trying to pass in a context variable as the value for css property but i can't seem to get it to work

```
<nav style="background-color: {{ nav_color }};">
```

i get this error message for the above in my template

```
at-rule or selector expected
```

i tried wrapping the variable in single quotes but it still won't work even though i know the variable gets passed when i inspect the element using devtools(it gets passed with the quotes and hence is not a valid css property)

i.e

```
<nav style="background-color: '{{ nav_color }}';">
// doesn't work 

//it gets rendered as this 
<nav style="background-color: '#24355C'>
```

here's my view

```
def about(request):
    context = {"about_page": "active", "nav_color": "#24355C"}
    return render(request, 'about.html', context)
```

Comment: This question doesn't give a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Please be more specific about exactly what *doesn't work* with your code.

Comment: It doesn't seem like anything is wrong. Putting context variables in template styles is valid. When you say it's not working, do you mean the wrong colour is shown? Is nothing shown? Please include some of your view code.